# Notepad++ Replace Multiple Words

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this text :

```
MD  0x1005  MD_IMAGE    0   15  63  6   6
MD  0x107F  MD_IMAGE    0   23  63  5   6
MD  0x112F  MD_IMAGE    0   31  64  5   5
MD  0x1131  MD_IMAGE    0   38  64  5   5
MD  0x1139  MD_IMAGE    0   16  71  5   5
```

and I want to replace it to :

```
MD  0x1005  MD_FILL_RECT    0xFFFF00FF  6   6
MD  0x107F  MD_FILL_RECT    0xFFFF00FF  5   6
MD  0x112F  MD_FILL_RECT    0xFFFF00FF  5   5
MD  0x1131  MD_FILL_RECT    0xFFFF00FF  5   5
MD  0x1139  MD_FILL_RECT    0xFFFF00FF  5   5
```

What is the regex command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace `MD_IMAGE\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*` to `MD_FILL_RECT    0xFFFF00FF`